# export 'useFormState' (imported as 'useFormState') was not found in 'react-dom' in React

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

I'm learning about states and input handling, and I'm looking at this tutorial: https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/hooks/useFormState

I'm trying to import useFormState from "react-dom" but I'm getting an error: export 'useFormState' (imported as 'useFormState') was not found in 'react-dom'

Here is the code that I have:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { useFormState } from "react-dom";
import "./App.css";

function Login(input, login) {
    const { state, form } = useFormState(login, null);

    return (
        <div className="login-wrapper">
            <h1>Login</h1>
            <div className="form-wrapper">
                <form action="form">
                    <input type="text" className="input-field" name="email" value={input} />
                    <input type="password" className="input-field" name="password" />
                    <button type="submit" className="login-button">Login</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Login;
```

Comment: What version of `react-dom` are you using?

Comment: @David My package.json file says that react-dom is version "^18.2.0"

Comment: That's currently only in canary and experimental releases per the docs you link.

Answer (score 1):

I updated my Next version:

```
npm i next@latest react@latest react-dom@latest eslint-config-next@latest
```

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/upgrading/version-14

Answer (score 0):

As it is clear in the documentation you provided, `useFormState` is only available in the `Canary` release, not yet in the stable release.

> The `useFormState` Hook is currently only available in React’s Canary and experimental channels.
> In addition, you need to use a framework that supports React Server Components to get the full benefit of useFormState.

You need to install a canary version of React, or use a framework that extends React Canary. Up to now, Jan 2024, Next.js is the only <sub>popular</sub> framework that extends React Canary. If you're using Next.js You won't see this error.

To install it: (at your own risk)

```bash
npm i react@canary react-dom@canary
```

You probably don't need to do it, If you need to use it use Next.js

Answer (score -1):

use it like this:

`import { experimental_useFormState as useFormState } from 'react-dom'`

if it throws an error, use `// @ts-ignore` at the line above

Answer (score -1):

2024 Update, you no longer need to add the `experimental` prefix. This works:

```
import { useFormState } from "react-dom";
```

in package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "next": "14.0.4"
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

in package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "next": "14.0.4"
  }
```

update the version of react and react-dom to 18

If this still doesn't work, then try updating @types/react and @types/react-dom to latest (this fixes my issue)